# Delete a file on iCloud drive automatically

Tags: applescript, icloud

To delete a file on the local filesystem without any dialog box is straightforward. But if you want to delete a file on iCloud drive you get an alert box, you have to quit.Because I want, that this happens automatically, I tried this:

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
set folderList to get items of folder "System:Users:user1:exampleFolder"
set deleteItem to item 1 of folderList
delete deleteItem
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        key code 36
    end tell
 end tell
```

It doesn't work. Is there an other way to quit the warning box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use icloud but System Events, rather than Finder, will usually delete files without a prompt.

If that doesn't work you can try:
Be careful with the following command. You can erase more than you want if you misplace the *.

```
set folderPath to "System:Users:user1:exampleFolder"
do shell script "rm  -r " & (quoted form of folderPath's POSIX path) & "/*"
```